# Running a Stored Procedure on All Databases, and Saving All Results Into A Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sp-msforeachdb

I'm trying to create a query in which I cycle through all the databases in a server, run a stored procedure on it, and save it to a results table.

This is what I have thus far:

```
CREATE table results (Severity INT, PurchaseOrderNumber INT,
                      PurchaseOrderLineNumber SMALLINT, ShipmentNumber SMALLINT,
                      ErrorCode int, ErrorText VARCHAR(256), DateCreated datetime)

EXECUTE sp_msForEachDB '
    IF "?" LIKE "VIS%"
        BEGIN
            USE "?"
            INSERT INTO results EXECUTE IC_PURCHASEORDER
        END
    '
SELECT * FROM results

DROP TABLE results
```

What I'm hoping to accomplish from this code is to run the IC_PURCHASEORDER stored procedure over all of the databases in the server, and record the result of that into the created results table. After that, I would be able to e-mail those results off to a supervisor, and then drop the table, but that's a job for another day. I know there exists a syntax error in the IF statement, that results in the following error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '{insert database name here}'.
```

Would it be possible to get some insight to what I'm trying to accomplish? Thanks!

Comment: Does your SP exist in every db?

Comment: I believe so, yes. I can add a check to ensure that at a later point, but as of right now, I'm assuming that all databases that I'm testing include the SP.

Comment: Answer below, will check proc exists before trying to execute it, else will tell you proc is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code as follows, should do the trick:

```
CREATE table results (Severity INT, PurchaseOrderNumber INT,
                          PurchaseOrderLineNumber SMALLINT, ShipmentNumber SMALLINT,
                          ErrorCode int, ErrorText VARCHAR(256), DateCreated datetime)

    exec sp_msForEachDB 'use [?];
                    if ''?'' like ''vis%''
                    begin
                        if object_id(''IC_PURCHASEORDER'') is not null
                        begin
                             INSERT INTO results EXECUTE IC_PURCHASEORDER
                        end
                        else
                        begin
                             print ''missing proc in ?''
                        end
                    end'

    SELECT * FROM results

    DROP TABLE results
```

Simple test... run this, it will tell you all db's like '%a%':

```
exec sp_msForEachDB 'use [?];
                    if ''?'' like ''%a%''
                    begin
                        select ''? is like a''
                    end
                    else
                    begin
                        select ''? is not like a''
                    end'
```

Comment: I had a missing `)` - i have also fixed the proc exist line-- I have updated it.  Try again.. else post error code please.

Comment: It seems to be getting through, until it comes up to inserting the data into the results table. The error I'm getting is:
`Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid object name 'results'.`
I'm guessing that this method of saving the results of the SP is clearly not the way to go. However, the check for seeing if the database has the stored procedure works like a charm.

Comment: Add a database pointer to insert.  Like `insert into report.dbo.results...`

Comment: Alright, it seems to be working as intended, and I'm getting a query result, as well as the results table being dropped at the end. Now I can work on the next step of what I need. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to have been some help.